# How float number 1.0E-12F covert to binary code?

Tags: java, binary, precision

Can someone explai how `1.0E-12F` covert to binary code `101011100011001011110011001100` step by step ? Thanks!

Test code:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        float c = 1.0E-12F;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(Float.floatToIntBits(c)));

        String myString = "101011100011001011110011001100";
        int intBits = Integer.parseInt(myString, 2);
        float myFloat = Float.intBitsToFloat(intBits);
        System.out.println(myFloat);
    }
}
```

result:

```
101011100011001011110011001100
1.0E-12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the description of 32-bit floating point on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

> [image]

So, `101011100011001011110011001100` is:

0 01010111 00011001011110011001100

*Sign:* 0 = Positive

*Exponent:* 01010111<sub>2</sub> = 87<sub>10</sub>   ⇒   2<sup>87 - 127</sup> = 2<sup>-40</sup>  ≈  9.094947e-13

*Fraction:* 1.00011001011110011001100<sub>2</sub>  ≈  1.0995116<sub>10</sub>

*Result:* 1.0995116 * 9.094947e-13  ≈  **1.0e-12**